# How to reserve old field when do some MongoDB aggregate?

Tags: mongodb

**Collection:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "device1",
    "type": "a",
    "para": {
      "number": 3,
      "resource": [
        "wifi",
        "bt"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "device2",
    "type": "b",
    "additional": "c",
    "para": {
      "number": 1,
      "resource": [
        "wifi",
        "3G"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "para": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$para.resource",
            "as": "item",
            "in": {
              "k": {
                "$concat": [
                  "resource",
                  {
                    "$toString": {
                      "$indexOfArray": [
                        "$para.resource",
                        "$$item"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "v": "$$item"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Current output:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "device1",
    "para": {
      "resource0": "wifi",
      "resource1": "bt"
    },
    "type": "a"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "additional": "c",
    "name": "device2",
    "para": {
      "resource0": "wifi",
      "resource1": "3G"
    },
    "type": "b"
  }
]
```

Detail see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bnqj5JzYnTv).

**What I expect is next:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "device1",
    "para": {
      "number": 3,
      "resource0": "wifi",
      "resource1": "bt"
    },
    "type": "a"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "additional": "c",
    "name": "device2",
    "para": {
      "number": 1,
      "resource0": "wifi",
      "resource1": "3G"
    },
    "type": "b"
  }
]
```

So, the aim is to change `resource` array to "map", the `resource0` is combined by a the fixed string `resource` plus the array index.

My query nearly done, but I don't know how to reserve the `number` in `para`. New to MongoDB, could you help?

> NOTE: maybe not only `number` in para, but also others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$mergeObjects` to merge `para` object and return from `arrayToObject` objects
- `$project` to remove `para.resource` array field

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "para": {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$para",
          {
            "$arrayToObject": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$para.resource",
                "as": "item",
                "in": {
                  "k": {
                    "$concat": [
                      "resource",
                      { "$toString": { "$indexOfArray": ["$para.resource", "$$item"] } }
                    ]
                  },
                  "v": "$$item"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { "para.resource": 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EsDDZUcZg8Z)

Comment: Nice, I almost posted :D, but keeping it in different variables